# match nested groups with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a text block as below:

```
group 1
name A
name B
name C
group 2
name X
name Y
name Z
group 3
name I
name II
name III
```

It's a nest groups, (group 1, group 2, group 3,...), and each group contains sub group, (name x, name y,name z,...).
How can I use regex to match this nested groups and sub groups with python?

I try below find all pattern to match outer groups fine, but how to add more code to match sub groups as well?

```
import re

content = """
group 1
name A
name B
name C
group 2
name X
name Y
name Z
group 3
name I
name II
name III
"""

m = re.findall("(group \d+).*?name",content,re.DOTALL)
if m:
    for e in m:
        print(e)
```

output:

```
: group 1
: group 2
: group 3
```

expected output:

```
: group 1
:    name A
:    name B
:    name C
: group 2
:    name X
:    name Y
:    name Z
: group 3
:    name I
:    name II
:    name III
```

Note, groups and sub groups number may not the same!

Comment: add more matching groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the expected output, you could put spaces before `name` items.

```py
print(re.sub(r"(?=name)", "   ", content).strip())
```

See the regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jZPcQK/1)

Or if you want to capture only `name` items after `group`, then use

```
(group \d+).+?(.*?)(?=.group|$)
```

See the regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jm4P9f/1)

```py
matches = re.findall(r"(group \d+).+?(.*?)(?=.group|$)", content, re.S) or []
for group, items in matches:
    print(group, end="\n   ")
    print(*items.split("\n"), sep="\n   ")
```

The second solution is for more dynamic use as `matches` is a list of `(group, items)` tuples, and we can easily convert it to a `dict` and get the `items` of only the needed group.

```py
groups = dict(matches)
print(groups.get("group 1"))
```

Comment: Thanks, would you please give some explain about (?=.group|$). is it a new group?

Comment: No, it is a positive lookahead that expects `group` or end of the string as block endpoint. And `.` before `group` ignores the last newline character.

Answer (score 1):

REGEX is not a must here. You can try the following code:

```
for i in content.split("\n"):
    print(i) if "group" in i else print(f"    {i}")
```

Answer (score 1):

A group starts with the word `group` and ends just before the next `group` or the end of the input.  Use a lookahead in the regex to check if `group` or end of string would match next.

```
pattern = r"(group\s\d+.*?)(?=group|\Z)"
```

Use the `re.DOTALL` flag so the `.` in the pattern will match newlines.

To indent the subgroups, use `.replace()` method or `split()` and `join()` methods:

```
for match in re.finditer(pattern, content, re.DOTALL):
    print(match[0].strip().replace('\n', '\n    '))
```

or

```
for match in re.finditer(pattern, content, re.DOTALL):
    print('\n'.join(match[0].strip().split()))
```